# I made a list in JavaScript, and try to put it on the webpage but it only comes up [object object] [object object]

Tags: javascript

I want to make a list of books in JavaScript, and first I made the code so it would print out in the console window, but now I want to have the list in web page, because via a DOM-event (button) I want the user to be able to put in another book in the list. With certain criterias. But now as I try to put it in web I only get object object] [object object], and since I'm a noob I don't understand how to merge so the list I made with JavaScript is shown in the webpage? Sorry if this is confusing.

```js
var array = [{
  "Title": "Machine Learning",
  "Year": 2020,
  "Price": 500
}, {
  "Title": "Artificial Intelligence",
  "Year": 2020,
  "Price": 1100
}, {
  "Title": "Algorithms and Data Structure",
  "Year": 1995,
  "Price": 400
}, {
  "Title": "Programming in C++",
  "Year": 1999,
  "Price": 200
}, {
  "Title": "Database Systems",
  "Year": 2020,
  "Price": 500
}];

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = array

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i])
}
```

```html
<h1>Velkommen til mitt arbeidskrav i emnet:
</h1>

<h1>Intro til programmering! </h1>

<div id="test">
</div>

<input id="NewBook" placeholder="Enter book"></input>
<button id="btnNewBook">Click to add book</button>

<p> My book list:
  <ul id="MyBookList">
  </ul>
```

Comment: How exactly did you expect an array of objects to be displayed?

Comment: If you just want to show the array data in the test div, then stringify the Javascipt object like so: `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(array)`

Comment: Ivar, haha no idea. As you can see, I'm totally noob at this point

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to show in the webpage is just an array (Object). You should loop over that array and show the title of the item, not `the item`.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("test");

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    el.innerHTML += `<div>${array[i].Title}</div>`;
}
```

Also a tip: instead of rebuilding the dom with innerHTML you might think to use `appendChild` or `insertAdjacentHTML` functions.

Comment: Thank you. Will try! But maybe it's also easier to just have the list print in console window, and the button in webpage, so when a user enter a valid book it will add in console window?

Comment: Yeah, you can do any of them. I am just showing you how to show any kind of data in the html. You can't show an array in the HTML, only the items of it. To show it as an array or object you'll have to use `JSON.stringify(object);`